# Is the manifold of complex points of a quotient of compact groups just the tangent bundle?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

In great generality a Lie group mod its maximal compact subgroup is contractible (for example this is true for all connected Lie groups). Whenever this is true then the Lie group $ D $ is diffeomorphic to a cartesian product of its maximal compact $ K $ with a contractible piece $ D/K $. So (again assuming $ G $ is connected or semisimple or some other sufficient condition to guarantee $ D/K $ contractible) if $ D $ is dimension $ 2n $ and the maximal compact subgroup is dimension $ n $ then we have a diffeomorphism
$$
D \cong K \times (D/K)
$$
where $ D/K $ is a contractible piece of dimension equal to $ K $. So $ D $ is diffeomorphic to a trivial $ \dim(K) $ dimensional real vector bundle over $ K $. On the other hand, since $ K $ is a Lie group it must be parallelizable. That is, the tangent bundle of $ K $ is a trivial $ \dim(K) $ dimensional real vector bundle over $ K $. In other words, we have that the Lie group $ D $ is diffeomorphic to the tangent bundle of its maximal compact subgroup,
$$
D \cong T(K).
$$
A particular case of this is when $ G $ is a linear algebraic group whose real points $ G_\mathbb{R} $ are compact. A compact group is always the maximal compact subgroup of its complexification (this follows from the fact that for subgroups of a complex linear algebraic group maximal compact is equivalent to compact plus Zariski dense). In other words, $ G_\mathbb{R} $ is the ($ n $ dimensional) maximal compact subgroup of the ( $ 2n $ real dimensional) group $ G_\mathbb{C} $. So, taking $ D=G_\mathbb{C} $ and $ K=G_\mathbb{R} $ in the argument above, we have that the complex points are diffeomorphic to the tangent bundle of the real points,
$$
G_\mathbb{C} \cong T(G_{\mathbb{R}}).
$$
Again this argument requires that the real points are compact. For example $ G_\mathbb{R} $ compact implies $ G_\mathbb{C} $ reductive group and so by Iwasawa decomposition for reductive groups we have that $ G_\mathbb{C} $ mod its maximal compact is contractible.

**Let $ G $ be a linear algebraic group and $ H $ a linear algebraic subgroup. Suppose the real points $ G_\mathbb{R}$, $H_\mathbb{R} $ are compact.  Consider the manifold of complex points
$$
M_\mathbb{C}=G_\mathbb{C}/H_\mathbb{C}.
$$
Then is the tangent bundle of
$$
M_\mathbb{R}=G_\mathbb{R}/H_\mathbb{R}
$$
diffeomorphic to $ M_\mathbb{C} $?**

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$Motivation:
$$
 \SO_{n+1}(\mathbb{C})/\SO_{n}(\mathbb{C}) 
$$
is diffeomorphic to the tangent bundle of the $ n $ sphere
$$
 S^n= \SO_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})/\SO_{n}(\mathbb{R}).
$$
More Motivation: When $ H $ is trivial the result follows from the discussion above.

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$Comment on the non-compact case: Without the compactness assumption this is false.  For example we can take $ H $ trivial and $ G=\SL_n $ (and $ n\geq 2 $ ). Then $ G_\mathbb{C}=\SL_n(\mathbb{C}) $ is homotopy equivalent to $ \SU_n $ while the tangent bundle of $ G_\mathbb{R}=\SL_n(\mathbb{R}) $ is homotopy equivalent to $ \SL_n(\mathbb{R}) $ which is homotopy equivalent to $ \SO_n(\mathbb{R}) $. But $ \SU_n $ and $ \SO_n(\mathbb{R}) $ are not homotopy equivalent. Thus $ \SL_n(\mathbb{C}) $ and the tangent bundle $ T(\SL_n(\mathbb{R})) $ are not homotopy equivalent so they certainly are not diffeomorphic.

Possible counter examples to consider next:
The Steifel manifold $ O_4/O_2 $ or the Grassmanian $ O_4/(O_2 \times O_2) $. What do the tangent bundles look like? Are they diffeomorphic to the complex points?

Comment: Just a note:  $G_{\mathbb R}/H_{\mathbb R}$ is not necessarily the real points of anything.  (Think of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)/\mu_2(\mathbb R)$, which is smaller than $(\operatorname{SL}_2/\mu_2)(\mathbb R) = \operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb R)$.)  I would be suspicious that that sort of issue might cause problems, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try $G=GL_1$, $H=\{1\}$.

Comment: I've added an assumption that the real points are compact. That is closer to the motivating example anyway. And it's really the case I'm most interested in. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: So, in particular, $G(\mathbb{R})$, if compact, should be connected if $G$ is?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly I believe that is correct. Certainly $ G(\mathbb{R}) $, if compact, is the maximal compact of $ G(\mathbb{C}) $. And the maximal compact of a connected lie group is always connected. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140622/are-maximal-compact-subgroups-of-connected-groups-connected/140638

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fact about the tangent space being the complexification is known to be true if $ G_\mathbb{R}/H_\mathbb{R} $ is a compact symmetric space. In other words, if $ H_\mathbb{R} $ is the fixed points of an involution of $ G_\mathbb{R} $. This includes, for example, all the spheres written as
$$
S^n \cong SO_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})/SO_n(\mathbb{R})
$$
This is taken directly from https://mathoverflow.net/a/414174/387190

Comment: You have linked to your question.  Did you mean to link to @JohannesHuisman's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/414174)?

Comment: Yes I mean his answer! Whenever I link I just copy paste the URL for the page. What's the trick for linking to a certain part of the page?

Comment: Below each answer (and the question itself), one of the small text labels says 'share'; clicking on that will give you the link.  For a comment, you instead click on the time stamp to get the link.

Comment: Oh wow this is perfect MO is such a well designed site! Thank you!

Comment: I think in fact a well designed site would make these affordances clearer, but now you know … until the SE overlords decide on another redesign to move this information somewhere else.

Comment: I have another question about MO tips and tricks. Is it considered rude to ask a user in the comments on one question if they would be willing to give their opinion on a different question?

Comment: The consensus on [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412741/is-the-manifold-of-complex-points-of-a-quotient-of-compact-groups-just-the-tange/414792#comment1063702_414792) is muddied.  See some discussion at [How to contact a MathOverflow user?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3634/how-to-contact-a-mathoverflow-user).

Comment: I see. Well if you happen to know any nice group actions on 4 manifolds I have a bounty out on this question https://mathoverflow.net/q/410547/387190. Seems like it can't possibly be true but I'm very curious to see a counterexample!

Comment: Ah.  If the user that you meant to ask was me, then I'm afraid I have to disappoint you.  Representation theory, not group actions on manifolds, is my bag, and I don't have anything much to contribute to the other question.

Comment: Fair enough! Speaking of rep theory would you happen to know anything about this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4362071/vector-with-trivial-stabilizer-in-so-3-representation I think maybe a generic vector in the 9 dimensional irrep of $ SO_3 $ should work (btw do you know if 9d irrep can be seen as the diagonal embedding of $ SO_3 \times SO_3 $ into adjoint form of $ SO_4 $ with $ SO_4/-1 \cong SO_3 \times SO_3 $ acting by conjugation on 9d space of $ 4 \times 4 $ traceless symmetric real matrices0